# Razor: Sum inside foreach to use outside the loop

Tags: c#, razor, foreach

Alright, I'll will keep this short and to the point.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
    {
        var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;

        DateTime thisDay = c.date;
        nextDay = thisDay.AddDays(1);

        sumKG += total;
    }
    @sumKG <br />
}
```

So this code right here does the calculation for `total` each time the `foreach` loops, each loop gives a big total to `sumKG`, but then the `for loop` makes the `foreach` loop again, which it should, and does a new calculation on new data because of other sql code that I also have, however, it adds that new calculation to the old value of `sumKG`. So in this case I know that the first `foreach loop` will give 23000 to `sumKG`and the second round it will give 5000, but in this case it gives me 23000, then 28000 (23000 + 5000), and so on, I dont want it that way, I want 23000 and then 5000.

Does this make any sense? And is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable to zero before going through the loop again:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
    {
        var total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;

        DateTime thisDay = c.date;
        nextDay = thisDay.AddDays(1);

        sumKG += total;
    }
    @sumKG <br />
    @sumKG = 0;
}
```

Or don't use `+=`

```
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var total = 0;
    foreach (var c in db.Query(getData))
    {
        total = c.kg * c.rep * c.sett;

        DateTime thisDay = c.date;
        nextDay = thisDay.AddDays(1);
    }
    @sumKG = total;
    @sumKG <br />
}
```

Comment: Haha ofc! Thank you very much!